# Core Image resize CIImage without loss of quality

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-image

Hi I am using "CILanczosScaleTransform" to resize my image by 50% and the result is blurry. I've read online that CILanczosScaleTransform isn't great. I don't want to add sharpness or "fake it." Any ideas to scale an image without the image getting blurry?

UPDATE: Here is a project example to download. You can clearly see the image on the right is much clearer than the image transformed on the left with CILanczosScaleTransform.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8yijwiv78hehuc/image%20resizer%20but%20blurry.zip?dl=0

[image]

Comment: CICrop? Scale the image by cropping? I don't understand. Are you saying Crop instead of "zoom" ?

Comment: you could simply use `imageView transform` property to resize the image?

Comment: Since a CIImage isn't a real image, it may be something else. The documentation says this filter i typically used to **scale down** an image. "Resize my image by 50%". Does that mean you are scaling up? Also, maybe it's an issue in rendering. Could you provide some code?

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the question with sample code and a screenshot. You can clearly see the image on the right is much clearer than the image transformed with CILanczosScaleTransform on the left. Please help if you can!

Comment: I'm probably much older than you and my eyes aren't as good. Still I'm seeing **no** difference - either here nor in the project I just downloaded. Simple things like edges (bull horns) all the way through the dead trees in the background right or the light and dark weed in front of the bull. Individual strands of bull fur(?) or hair(?) on it's left front? Same - no difference.

Comment: Really? Wow! The photo is blurry on my screen. I'm on a retina screen. Could that be where the issue is????

Comment: Hey Jim! i'm struggling for weeks on this issue.. Did you solved it?

Comment: @RoiMulia nope :( let me know if you do!

Comment: I think first resizing to UIImage and than convert to CIImage will be the solution..

Answer (score 2):

`CGBitmapContext` has always been solid for me. Refer here: http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Comment: Thank you! Tried it. Didn't work. Please see the sample project I added. You can clearly see the image on the left, transformed with CILanczosScaleTransform is blurry.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're set on using `CILanczosScaleTransform`?

Comment: Hi Wes. I tried CGBitmapContext but it was just as blurred. I don't understand why CILanczosScaleTransform scales to a blurry image.

Comment: You also have to take into account the physical size at which you are displaying the images. In your example above one is supposedly 10% smaller than the other yet you are showing them at the same physical size rather than their literal sizes and thus the smaller one would be blurred.

Comment: Sorry Wes, there is a miscommunication. These are both the same image. The one of the left is being being scaled with CILanczosScaleTransform and the other is just in an image well being scaled by just making the view smaller. The image well creates a nice, sharp, scaled image. The CILanczosScaleTransform view doesn't.